# Keep CSS3 hover state when unhovered

Tags: jquery, html, forms, css

I'm trying to keep the magnified lens in the hovered state when the user clicks the input field instead of returning back to the question mark. I've tried the following jQuery but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    $(".srchbtn").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".srchbtn").addClass('hover');
    });
```

Here's a link to the CodePen: http://cdpn.io/hcadj

Comment: one("mouseover",[...] ? check the typo hehe

Comment: The solution doesn't work, could you explain where the typo is?

Comment: He was trying to point out that you entered "one" instead of "on" only he forgot how to use his words.

Comment: Ah ok, the typo still doesn't achieve the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

1. You mention you want your action to happen "*when the user clicks*" but bind the handler to the `mouseover` event instead of the `click`
2. You add a class with name `hover` to the element, but your have no rule using that class..

So try changing your css rule to

```
.srchbtn:hover,
.srchbtn.hover{ /*add this line and the comma in the previous one*/
  /*your properties here*/
 }
```

(*you might even want to change the first selector to `.search:hover .srchbtn`*)

and change your script to

```
$(".srchbtn").one("click", function() {
    $(".srchbtn").addClass('hover');
});
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/IeEmd

Comment: This method causes animation issues when moving the mouse over to the input field (the animation restarts causing the magnify to flicker).

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is the CSS. You use the :hover, which is only active when the mouse is over it. Using jQuery, you can use `.mouseenter()` to indicate the css should happen when you enter, but not go away when you leave.

   $('.srchbtn').mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).css({"display":"block","height":"10px","width":"10px"});
   });

The display:block, height and width are just examples of how you could enter CSS to it only on mouseenter, but not go away (which you could get with `mouseleave();`).

1. Alternatively, another option of solving your issue is to make the question-field a child of the questionmark-div. That way, when you hover over the question-field, you are technically still hovering over the question mark itself, making the CSS still apply the :hover state.

Pick either!

Edit after re-reading your question, you might want to go for option 2, since when the user focuses neither the question mark or the question-field, it'll revert back to it's non:hover state.